# backup postgres database password issue

Tags: backup, authentication, postgresql

I've got a postgres database that I want to backup regularly. For that, I'd like to use the automated backup script [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)

Usually I to proceed admin tasks I use these command:

```
> sudo -i -u postgres
> psql
```

No password is requested and I can dump manually my database. It's not too bad.

Using the automated script I face a password issue. It asks me for `postgres` password. I've never set it up and I thought I shouldn't need to set it up as the example given above showed.

Here is how is configured my `pg_hba.conf`.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Do I really need to set a `postgres` password for running my script?

Comment: As what user are you executing the backup script and how are you executing it?

Comment: Actually it's now working. I will answer to myself to keep trace of how it works. I execute the script as a system user who's not a postgres user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I found out in order to have this script running from a system user.

1. I wasn't able to have it running without setting a password for `postgres`

   $ sudo -i -u postgres

   $ psql

   $ ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
2. Then create a `.pgpass` file in the user system home who's running the script.

   $ echo '*:*:*:postgres:new_password' > ~/.pgpass

   $ chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
3. That's it.

My errors was:

- to think that I could handle it without setting the a postgres password.
- trying to place the .pgpass in /var/lib/postgresql (postgres home) instead of user system home.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running script as root:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

If you are running script as other system user, add sudo permission for this user with `visudo` before executing above command.

```
 <Systemuser> ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/psql
```